# Table structure by div tag in html

Tags: html, css-tables

I'm using div instead of table but I am not getting the border increased while the content increase in a column.

```
<div class="divTable">
             <div class="headRow">
                <div class="divCell" align="center">Customer ID</div>
                <div  class="divCell">Customer Name</div>
                <div  class="divCell">Customer Address</div>
             </div>
            <div class="divRow">
                  <div class="divCell">001</div>
                <div class="divCell">002</div>
                <div class="divCell">am unable to get the white space between col while the content increases</div>
            </div>
            <div class="divRow">
                <div class="divCell">xxx</div>
                <div class="divCell">yyy</div>
                <div class="divCell">www</div>
           </div>
            <div class="divRow">
                <div class="divCell">ttt</div>
                <div class="divCell">uuu</div>
                <div class="divCell">Mkkk</div>
           </div>

      </div>

.divTable{
  display:table;         
  width:auto;         
  background-color:#eee;         
  border:1px solid  #666666;         
  border-spacing:5px;
}
.divRow{
  display:table-row;
  width:auto;
  clear:both;
    background-color:#ccc;  
}
.divCell{
  float:left;
  display:table-column;         
  width:100px;         
border-left: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

Kindly go through the  link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/H4Zug/

Comment: This looks like a tabular data so why use div instead of table?

Comment: @Mr.Alien If you want to animate the table, it's easier to animate a div than a row or a cell. For example, rows that slides in and out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `display:table-cell` instead of `display:table-column` and remove `float:left`  for `.divCell`.

And add this style:

```
.headRow{
    display:table-row;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Y6cJ/3/